# How to have a persistent connection with Net in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telnet

I am using a Telnet - client to validate the emails, I connect to the server and it responds with 250 but when I write another command and ask for the answer, it simply does not answer me.

This is my code:

```
 function ConnectTelnet(){
  //var connection = new telnet();
  var response;
  var HOST = 'mail.dominio.com'; 
  var PORT = 25;

  var net = require('net');
  var client = net.connect(25,'mail.dominio.com',function(){
    console.log('connected to server!');
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);

    client.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('Received: ' + data);
      response = data;
     if(response.indexOf("220") === -1){
    client.write('EHLO dominio.com')
    console.log(data)
  }
    });
  })
}
```

Does anyone know how I can continue? Thanks :)

Comment: How about [`client.write`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback)?

Comment: I have modified the code of the question so you can see that I try to use the client.write () but it just does not print a response @Bergi

Comment: What do you mean by "*it does not print a response*"? Did you receive any data, and does it contain `"220"`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't send the data, get an answer and then send more data on the same connection. TCP does not send messages "separately". TCP is a stream protocol, which means that when you write bytes to the socket, you get the same bytes in the same order at the receiving end. There is no notion of "message boundaries" or "packets" anything of the sort.

If you want to do that, you need to make a new connection every time.

This is how I did to send several EHLO on the same connection:

```
const net = require('net');
const client = net.createConnection({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 1025 }, () => {
  console.log('connected to server!');
  checkEHLO(client, [ 'xxx@xxx.xxx', 'xxx@xxx.xxx', 'xxx@xxx.xxx' ]);
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});

function checkEHLO(client, emails){
    emails.forEach((email) => {
        client.write('EHLO ' + email + '\n');
    });
}
```

And this was the response I got:

```
connected to server!
220 127.0.0.1 ESMTP Service Ready
250-Hello xxx@xxx.xxx
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-Hello xxx@xxx.xxx
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-Hello xxx@xxx.xxx
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
```

Comment: The usual solution to an issue like this is NOT to create a new connection every time, but to invent or use a data protocol that defines messages and delimiters between messages.  The simplest scheme is a text-based scheme that ends each message with a carriage return character.  There are many, many other designs that define message formats within a stream protocol.